# Updating Field From 2 Combo Boxes (Risk Matrix)

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a table 'tblInfo' and the risk matrix below:[image: Risk Matrix]

I have 2 combo boxes, 1 of which has a list of the headings of this matrix, one has a list of the first column of the matrix.

I would like to be able to populate a field, 'Risk' in 'tblInfo' from the risk matrix depending on what both the comobo boxes are set to.

For example, if combo box 1 = "Insignificant" and combo box 2 = "Rapid 5 to 15 min" then I would like the field 'Risk' to be populated with 'No Alarm' for this particular record.

The only way I can think of doing this is a very tedious if statement followed by an update query to populate that field for that record. I have done this in ms excel using 'Vlookup' and 'Match' but I don't believe I can do so in ms access.

Is there a way I can complete this without a tedious if statement?

Comment: Need a 'lookup' table called Risks that defines these associations. Have 4 fields: RiskID, TimeAvailable, RiskLevel, ResponseLevel. Create records for every combination. Looks like 25 records. Then employ cascading combobox. Select RiskLevel in first combobox. Filter second combobox list to associated TimeAvailable and RiskLevel records. Select TimeAvailable and save that RiskID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this problem by following the steps outlined in June7's comments of this question.

They as follows:

Need a 'lookup' table called Risks that defines these associations. Have 4 fields: RiskID, TimeAvailable, RiskLevel, ResponseLevel.

Create records for every combination. Looks like 25 records.

Then employ cascading combobox. Select RiskLevel in first combobox. Filter second combobox list to associated TimeAvailable and RiskLevel records. Select TimeAvailable and save that RiskID

Credit for the solution goes to June7 (as can be seen in the comments)